# Getting Confused While Interpreting a Statement Of Multidimensional Vectors in c++

Tags: c++, vector

I am kind of new to Working With 2D Vectors With C++ , and Often times I get confused while I am
Working With 2D Vectors in C++ . I was going through someone's code and I am getting confused while interpreting this line of code :

`vector<vector<int>> dp(n, vector<int>(m));`

Here , m and n are number of rows and columns of a Grid .

Can Somebody please explain to me in detail , what does this statement mean ?

Comment: This is just invoking various [vector constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).

Answer (score 6):

This line:

```
vector<vector<int>> dp(n, vector<int>(m));
```

is invoking a [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) of `std::vector`.

For `dp`, the first argument is the number of elements, and the second argument is the value to be inserted those many times.

The inner vector is not specifying the argument value, which will insert default values (`0` in the case of `int`).

So in this case, you are creating a vector with `n` rows, where each row has `m` elements in it, and each of the elements is `0`.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/

One of the constructors of Vector takes param 1 as the number of elements and 2 as the value of those elements.  In this case, you are creating a vector named dp... it will have n elements...  and each of those elements will be initialized as a new vector of size m elements.

The n and m values only really pertain to the initial size... Vector will automatically resize itself as new elements are added or as you explicitly tell it to if your expect significant size changes to be coming

Answer (score 2):

You can break it down if it helps

```
vector<vector<int>> dp(n, vector<int>(m));
```

is effectively the same as

```
vector<int> row(m);
vector<vector<int>> dp(n, row);
```

All the first version does is eliminate the `row` variable.